# How to convert HashMap to own type array?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have my hash map of type:

```
private HashMap<String, HashMapObject> likesYearHashMap;
```

where HashMapObject :

```
public class HashMapObject  {

private int count;
private String id;

public HashMapObject(int count, String id) {
    super();
    this.count = count;
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

how to convert values into my HashMap to HashMapObject [] array?

I get error of cast getting likesYearHashMap.values();

Comment: `Map#values()` returns a `Collection`. Iterate over it and add its element to your array.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
map.values().toArray(new HashMapObject[map.size()])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
likesYearHashMap.values().toArray (new HashMapObject[likesYearHashMap.size ()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Vakh and @NinChimpsky i post the complete solution:

To convert into array :

```
HashMapObject[] array = new HashMapObject[likesYearHashMap.size()];
likesYearHashMap.values().toArray(array);
```

To convert to ArrayList

```
Collection<HashMapObject> values = likesYearHashMap.values();
ArrayList<HashMapObject> arrayList= new ArrayList<HashMapObject>(values);
```